# Allowing leading zero in sql for a text format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently having issues when using ms sql server to get to print out leading zero's for a number based column (which the client has set up that way). It is meant to be a date type but the client has set it up as number so I am using a work around.

It is okay if that column is for instance 11032019 but it does cause problems when the column has a value for instance 08032019 or 8032019

I have tried to pad it with a right function to add '00' but that comes to no avail using mssqlserver.

So for instance something like this:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(13022018,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/') , 103),0)

CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(11032019,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/') , 103)
```

The above works okay but the issue lies on the below, if it has leading 0 or just as below

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(8022019,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/') , 103)
```

I think I am close what I need is it should output for the example that works 2019-03-11 00:00:00.000

but for the one that does not work it just simple throws an error of conversion failed and I've tested it that its due to the leading zero not being accepted by ms sql

Comment: I am baffled.  You are talking about padding a number, then you are using date/times in the code.  Then you bring in time values.  What are you really trying to do?  Sample data and desired results really help!

Comment: What is the data type of your actual input -- text or a number? You're using numbers, but if you have "leading zeroes" the input should be text. `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF('08022019',5,0,'/'),3,0,'/') , 103)` works just fine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert apologise I will change it as it's meant to be numbers, that was my bad. I will change it in the main bit

Comment: @GordonLinoff apologise for that, its a number field input which the client wants as is and I am trying to make it into a date as its an accounting date as shown in the example above. I need the output as: 2019-03-11 00:00:00.000

Comment: @JeroenMostert also to emphasise if it we're text I think the '8032019' example would not work with my current method. Maybe might need to ask the client to make their data a bit more 'clean'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option using `left()` and `right()`.   This also works if the values were INTs.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('11032019')
,('08032019')
,('8032019')


Select *
      ,NewValue = try_convert(date
                             ,right(SomeCol,4)
                             +left(right('00'+SomeCol,8),4)
                             )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol     NewValue
11032019    2019-11-03
08032019    2019-08-03
8032019     2019-08-03
```

> **EDIT - Ugly Update**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (11032019)
,(8032019)
,(80219)

Set DateFormat DMY

Select *
      ,NewValue = try_convert(date,
                  stuff(right('0'+left(SomeCol,len(SomeCol)-len(right(SomeCol,IIF(Len(SomeCol)<7,2,4)))),4),3,0,'/')
                + '/'
                + right(SomeCol,IIF(Len(SomeCol)<7,2,4))
                )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol     NewValue
11032019    2019-03-11
8032019     2019-03-08
80219       2019-02-08
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried values with int for instance 13022018 and this gives me null

Comment: @kdawg That looks like DDMMYYYY  if all your data is in this format, you can SET DATEFORMAT DMY

Comment: The thing is it goes into the database as number and thats how the client has it (working on their db) but need to make it into a dateformat as you said when outputting. My workaround for it was the one I described above but it does no work right with single digit dates i.e. 80219 or even 080219

Comment: @kdawg  You really need to provide a proper sample and less ambiguous dates is 0802 August 2 or Feb 8.

Comment: Apologise John - its feb ..the issue with providing data is it being confidential and client related. I will try to source some sample files though

Comment: @kdawg  Feb it is... For the record, there is nothing confidential regarding a date string with no context.   We only need to see data patterns..    One moment, and I'll make some changes.

Comment: @kdawg See Update.  Got a little ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pad a number to a given length, with leading zeros, then one method is:

```
select right(concat(replicate('0', 10), 11032019), 10)
```

You can also use `format()`:

```
format(11032019, '0000000000')
```

or:

```
format(11032019, 'D10')
```

Comment: I'd still prefer `REPLICATE('0', 10)` for the format string so you don't have to count, but `'D10'` is clearer and shorter still.

Answer (score 0):

Try add 100000000 (8 zeroes, 10 is ok too) , convert to char and take last 8 chars

```
select STUFF(STUFF(right(1000000000 + 8022019,8) ,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/')
```

Comment: Please add explanation around your code. So that OP and future reader can easily understand your answer.

Comment: @SangamBelose , ok